# add class for equivalent other ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="list" multiple=multiple>
    <option value="1" id="one" selected="selected">one </option>
    <option value="2" id="two" selected="selected">two </option>
    <option value="3" id="three">three </option>
</select>

<ul id="uli">
    <li aaa="one">one</li>
    <li aaa="two">two</li>
    <li aaa="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

With the CSS:

```
.back {
 color: red;
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
$("#list").find("option:selected").each(function() {
    // logic here
});
```

Into the `each()` callback, I want to add class for equivalent in uli. I would like to use `addClass(.back)` for li where attr `aaa` == `id` for list.

live: http://jsfiddle.net/yjL9n/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>$('li[aaa=' + this.id + ']').addClass('back');</strike>

```
$('table').find('td[aaa="'+this.id+'"]').addClass('back');
```

added to the inner part of [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjL9n/3/) will do it. **Updated** based on comment from OP.

Comment: You just need to change the elements in the selector(s). You might want to read up on [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
$("#uli").find('[aaa="'+this.id+'"]')
    .addClass('back');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjL9n/4/

Comment: You can have another +1 if you tidy up the selectors! :D

Comment: is it clean enough for you? ;)

Comment: i would like make this for table, and not for ul/li

Comment: id does not change at all, apart from original selector #uli - as your table lack id (you should add it and update selector)

Answer (score 2):

This works (and is tidier):

```
$("#list option:selected").each(function() { 
    $('#uli li[aaa="' + this.id + '"]').addClass('back');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjL9n/5/

However I wouldn't use aaa as an attribute!

Comment: as for merging all selectors into one string instead using find - there is a deep difference between this two types. When jQuery finds long string selector, it always runs it's css parsing unit (sizzle), and when find are used - it can usually manage it on it's own. But being honest i'm not sure if it covers this example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#list").find("option:selected").each(function() {
   $("#uli").find('[aaa="'+this.id+'"]').addClass('back');
});
```